# Вылетает синий экран смерти при попытке запустить программу Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, macos

При попытке запустить простейший Hello World на эмуляторе, мой Macbook Pro перезагружается, выдавая синий экран смерти, если же подключать телефон, то на перезагрузку уходит и телефон и компьютер. Что делать?

Comment: Во время запуска эмулятор просмотрите логи, там должна быть ошибка. В зависимости от нее ищите решение проблемы в интернете.

Comment: Дело в том, что лог чистится после вылета, но раньше были проблемы такого типа Emulator:Warning:Quick Boot/Snapshot not supported on this machine.A CPU + UG feature is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
Я решил испробовать API меньше 21 так как нарыл такое решение проблемы, но в итоге получил вылеты

Comment: Попробуйте заменить эмулятор на Genymotion или какой то другой. У одного человека была такая проблема, перед синим экраном, смотрел логи, такая же ошибка была.